# Azure firewall - how to ensure outbound traffic from a VM leaving the firewall with source = the VM's public IP?

Tags: firewall, azure, nat

I provisioned a VM and an Azure Firewall. I created a public IP for the VM and added a DNAT on the Firewall. It works fine when I access from the Internet to the VM by using its public IP. However, I notice when I am in the VM and reach out to the Internet, the Firewall's public IP instead of the VM's public IP is used. Is there a way to configure the firewall to ensure outgoing traffic from the VM leaves the firewall with source IP = VM's public IP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create Route table

Route Table Name : Outbound to FW
Address Prefix 0.0.0.0/0 
Next Hop : Your firewall internal IP

Attached the route table to the subnet of the VM.